# How do I get SingleOrDefault to return object by reference from a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, byref

Consider these lines of code:

```
  //prodProdGroup is a list within the itm object that I need to search. The items
  //within the list are of type ProductionCostCalcHelper. I need to find one
  //of the ProductionCostCalcHelper records in the list, calculate its total dollar value
  //and assign it the value

  ProductionCostCalcHelper prodGroupItm = itm.prodProdGroup.SingleOrDefault(f => f.MAST_PROJ.Trim() == laborItm.MAST_PROJ.Trim());
  ProductionCostCalcHelper prodGroupItm2 = itm.prodProdGroup.SingleOrDefault(f => f.MAST_PROJ.Trim() == laborItm.MAST_PROJ.Trim());

  if (prodGroupItm != null)
  {
        prodGroupItm.TOTAL_DOLLAR = avgDollarsPerHour * prodGroupItm.HOURS;
  }
```

I'm assuming that the SingleOrDefault method would return the object by reference but it doesn't. After changing the TOTAL_DOLLAR amount of ProdGroupItm, ProdGroupItm2 remains the same proving that they are not referencing what is in the list. Why is this? Is there a way to update the value of the object within the list?

Comment: Is `ProductionCostCalcHelper` a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen if your `ProductionCostCalcHelper` type is a mutable `struct`.
**Don't do that**; [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Every time you pass a `struct` around, the entire value is copied to whatever you're passing it to.

Use a class instead.

Comment: Thank you but it's a class, not a struct.

Comment: Then that shouldn't be happening.  Are you using LINQ to SQL?  What type is `itm.prodProdGroup`?

Comment: I just found out the answer. prodProdGroup was an IEnumerable. I Changed it to IList and it now works. What a waste of a day. Thank you for your help.